# UITableView Data disappears when scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, scroll

I have  a `UITableView` in which i am fetching data from server and displaying it in the `UITableViewCell`. But data disappears while scrolling . Please help .

Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` :-

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"CellIdentifier";
    CCCustomCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    //UITableViewCell *cell=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[CCCustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }


    cell.keyText.text=[[[[arraySuper objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] allKeys] objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.objectText.text=[[[[arraySuper objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];

    [cell.objectText addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell.objectText
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:nil
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                               multiplier:1.0
                                                                 constant:(cell.objectText.text.length>0)?50:0]];

    [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    tableView.allowsSelection=YES;

      if (indexPath.row==0)
    {
        cell.keyText.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:62.0/255.0 green:60.0/255.0 blue:100.0/255.0 alpha:1];
        cell.keyText.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15];
        [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    }
    else
    {
        cell.keyText.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:74.0/255.0 green:144.0/255.0 blue:226.0/255.0 alpha:1];
        cell.keyText.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13];
        cell.objectText.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:62.0/255.0 green:60.0/255.0 blue:100.0/255.0 alpha:1];
        cell.objectText.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13];
        cell.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    }

       return cell;
}
```

Comment: can you add some code where you created UITableView?

Comment: IBOutlet UITableView *CCTableView;
    [CCTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CCCustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
    [CCTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

Comment: @LalitKumar - This is used to create UITableView

Comment: and how you add in self.view

Comment: check this answer. will help http://stackoverflow.com/a/26467165/3976183

Comment: Not able to do it perfectly ./@LalitKumar

Answer (score 1):

You are having cell dequeue issue....Yor are not getting proper cell height. Follow the following method for assigning data & getting proper height. Check your cell having proper height

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static YOUR_TABLEVIEW_CELL *sizingCell = nil;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"YOUR_TABLEVIEW_CELL_IDENTIFIER";
    sizingCell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (sizingCell==nil)
   {
       sizingCell=[[YOUR_TABLEVIEW_CELL alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }
    [self configureFareIssueCell:sizingCell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return [self calculateHeightForConfiguredSizingCell:sizingCell];
}

//assign all the labels  here
- (void)configureFareIssueCell:(YOUR_TABLEVIEW_CELL* )cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //e.g 
   cell.lbl.text=@"YOUR_TEXT";
   cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"NAME_OF_YOUR_IMAGE"];
} 

- (CGFloat)calculateHeightForConfiguredSizingCell:(YOUR_TABLEVIEW_CELL *)sizingCell
{
    CGSize size = [sizingCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
   return size.height + 1.0f; // Add 1.0f for the cell separator height
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"YOUR_TABLEVIEW_CELL_IDENTIFIER";
  YOUR_TABLEVIEW_CELL   *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_TABLEVIEW_CELL_IDENTIFIER"];
if (cell==nil)
{
    cell=[[YOUR_TABLEVIEW_CELL alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }
   [self configureFareIssueCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
  return cell;
 }
```

Comment: Your code works , but i need to change the frame of cell.lbl.text .

Comment: How to do that as the cell.lbl.frame doesn`t go anything @swapnali patil

Comment: change the frame in configureFareIssueCell: method

Comment: Doesn`t make any change @swapnali patil

Comment: can you please check you are adding bottom constraint to the last object...this might be coz the problem

Comment: I have posted an answer , Please have a look and reply me .. THANKS .

Answer (score 1):

Try Using

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

instead of

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

Comment: Still problem resides @Lalit Kumar

Answer (score 0):

You are changing constraints at runtime.

```
[cell.objectText addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell.objectText
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                               toItem:nil
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                           multiplier:1.0
                                                             constant:(cell.objectText.text.length>0)?50:0]];
```

Instead of this, just add auto layout constraints form storyboard to your label. And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method just update constraints according to your requirement.

Comment: Can you please give an example , As i am not able to figure out what to do .?